# Why in React I can not retrieve data from useState without distructuring?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

Why in React I can not retrieve data from useState without distructuring? Like this:

```
const name = useState('kana')[0];
const setName = useState('kana')[1];
```

I know I can do it like this:

```
const stateName = useState('kana')
const name = stateName[0];
const setName = stateName[1];
```

but why I can not do it like I did in first example??

Comment: in the first example you are calling the useState function twice. you can write it in 1 line correctly like this: const [name, setName] = useState("kana")

Comment: Because `useState` returns an array.

Comment: You can, but it'll be 2 independent state variables. for one you'll have only value and for the second the set state function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the first example is that you're calling useState twice. When you do that, React is creating and managing two entirely different pieces of state. As a result, the "name" variable and the "setName" function are entirely separate.

Your 'name' const on the first line has no way to be updated.

Comment: Yes, now I understand, thank you very much!